# How to get subtitles' currently displayed text

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webvtt

I would like to extract the subtitle text on a paused video frame of external website (like youtube.com) through console.log.

It is assumed that the external website provides the subtitles through a webvtt or similar file.

As the subtitle text is possibly part of the DOM, can JavaScript code be used in the browser's Developer Console to extract the text & display it through console.log() after detecting the time at which it was paused?

Comment: You need a webvtt parser and extract the text at the right time...

Comment: As the subtitle text is possibly part of the DOM, can JavaScript code be used in the browser's Developer Console to extract the text after detecting the time at which it was paused? Is there any way to invoke a webvtt parser through JS in the Console?

Comment: "external website"? What does it mean? You are on /site-A.com/ and want to get the value at /site-B.com/?

Comment: @Kaiido By external site, I meant site like youtube.com, not owned by me. I would like to extract subtitle text on a frame on which I've paused possibly through console.log

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  There is no such thing as `extract X through console.log`.  Perhaps you meant to say `extract X, and then print it with console.log`

Comment: @JK, Yes. I edited the question to make it more specific with the feedback provided. Please let me know if any further clarification is required

Comment: You shouldn't need any help figuring out how to print something with console.log.  So really the question should have just been `How to extract X?` Don't include unnecessary questions.

Comment: @JK I mentioned console.log thinking it would help visualize the use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the video's [`.textTracks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrackList), from which you'll be able to access its `activeCues` from where you can get their [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VTTCue) value:

```js
initTrack();
video.addEventListener('pause', e => {
 const track = [ ...video.textTracks ]
   .find( track => track.mode === "showing" );
 const texts = [...track.activeCues].map( cue => cue.text );
 console.log( texts.join('\n') );
});


// just to make a VTT accessible in Snippet
function initTrack() {
  const track = document.querySelector("track");
  let vttText = `WEBVTT`;
  for( let i=0; i<35; i++ ) {
    const t1 = (i + '').padStart(2 , '0');
    const t2 = ((i+1) + '').padStart(2 , '0');
    vttText += `
      00:00:${t1}.000 --> 00:00:${t2}.000
      Test${i}`
  }
  const vttBlob = new Blob([vttText], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  track.src = URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

```css
video { max-height: 150px;  }
::cue { font-size: 30px }
```

```html
<div>
  <video id="video" controls>
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm">
    <track default kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en"/>
  </video>
</div>
```

And if you wish to do it while it's playing, then you can listen for the [*cuechange*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/cuechange_event) event:

```js
initTrack();
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", (evt) => {
  const track = [...video.textTracks]
    .find(track => track.mode === "showing");
  track.oncuechange = (evt) => {
    const texts = [...track.activeCues].map(cue => cue.text);
    console.log(texts.join("\n"));
  };
});

// just to make a VTT accessible in Snippet
function initTrack() {
  const track = document.querySelector("track");
  let vttText = `WEBVTT`;
  for (let i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    const t1 = (i + '').padStart(2, '0');
    const t2 = ((i + 1) + '').padStart(2, '0');
    vttText += `
      00:00:${t1}.000 --> 00:00:${t2}.000
      Test${i}`
  }
  const vttBlob = new Blob([vttText], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  track.src = URL.createObjectURL(vttBlob);
}
```

```css
video {
  max-height: 150px;
}

::cue {
  font-size: 30px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <video id="video" controls>
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm">
    <track default kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en"/>
  </video>
</div>
```